# VBA userform getting a filepath from sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that i have made and it needs to send information to multiple workbook and that is fine.

However these workbook change monthly and i would like to put the file path in a cell and referance that in my code so that the code will not be needing to be changed monthly. Just the filepath in the cell.
Thanks for the help!

```
Dim wb As Workbook
            Dim ws As Worksheet

                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Link1")
                    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet test")



                    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = Me.T1.Value
                    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = Me.T2.Value
                    ws.Cells(2, 5).Value = Me.T3.Value
                    ws.Cells(2, 6).Value = Me.T4.Value
                    ws.Cells(2, 7).Value = Me.T5.Value
                    ws.Cells(2, 8).Value = Me.T6.Value
                    ws.Cells(2, 9).Value = Me.T7.Value
```

Comment: What you are asking is so easy. Can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried many different ways and have not had luck. I posted what I have now above

Comment: will you just put file path in the cell or the filename as well?

Comment: I could do either.

Answer (score 2):

If the cell only have file path `(Ex: C:\Temp\)` then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim flName As String, flPath As String

    '~~> Let's say the path is in Cell A1 of Sheet1
    '~~> Change as applicable
    flPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    If Right(flPath, 1) <> "\" Then flPath = flPath & "\"

    '~~> This is the file name
    flName = "Sample.xlsx"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=flPath & flName)

    With wb
        '~~> Do your stuff
    End With
End Sub
```

And if the cell have file name and path `(Ex: C:\Temp\MyFile.xlsx)` then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim flName As String

    '~~> Let's say the name & path is in Cell A1 of Sheet1
    '~~> Change as applicable
    flName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=flName)

    With wb
        '~~> Do your stuff
    End With
End Sub
```